why this code return me null if id specific entry available in database
public Contact getContactById(int id) {
         
    Contact contact=null;
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Contact where id=:id");
    query.setParameter("id",id);
    List<Contact> list = query.list();
    transaction.commit();
    if(!list.isEmpty())
    {
        contact=list.get(0);
    }
    return contact;
}

i want o specific contact object related to id

You can set the show sql property to true, print the query in the console, take that query, and see whether that returns any result.

no its not working its show me ClassCastException and return again null

i will try fetch data to username but it is also show me null

also i have used get() method but result is same null

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
